# Java XML Parsing: Document (DeferredDocumentImpl) vs Document (XMLDocument) Discrepancy in Different Environments

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm encountering an issue with XML parsing in Java 8 where the same code behaves differently in production compared to lower environments.

Here's the Java code snippet that prints the XML nodeValue using a partial XPath:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class XMLParserDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
final String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
"<securityDataUpdated xmlns:ns0=\"http://xmlns.paddy.com/canonical/1\" xmlns=\"http://xmlns.paddy.com/canonical/2.1\" version=\"362\">\n" +
" <ns0:header>\n" +
" <ns0:correlationId>c3004188-ae3d-11ee-a506-0242ac120002</ns0:correlationId>\n" +
" <ns0:sourceSystem>CASH</ns0:sourceSystem>\n" +
" <ns0:initialCreationDate>2017-05-04</ns0:initialCreationDate>\n" +
" <ns0:creationTimestamp>2023-10-20T03:59:39.256-04:00</ns0:creationTimestamp>\n" +
" </ns0:header>\n" +
" <ns0:comment>hhga1002M</ns0:comment>\n" +
" <securityTypeIndicator>CASH FLOW</securityTypeIndicator>\n" +
" <publishingAssetClass>CF</publishingAssetClass>\n" +
" <cashInformation active=\"true\">\n" +
" <productType system=\"BRDR\">FORWARD</productType>\n" +
" <name>COP Onsh Fwd OutRt 10Y</name>\n" +
" <identifier type=\"ICEBERG-UNIQUE\">IX35571185-0</identifier>\n" +
" <identifier type=\"TICKER\">CLO+10Y</identifier>\n" +
" <identifier type=\"ICEBERG-ID-GLOBAL\">BBG00GMFSG55</identifier>\n" +
" <identifier type=\"PADDY-ID\">92157699</identifier>\n" +
" <identifier type=\"BRDR-UNIQUE-ID\">92157699-NA-NA</identifier>\n" +
" <issue active=\"true\">\n" +
" <issueActivityStatus>ACTIVE</issueActivityStatus>\n" +
" </issue>\n" +
" <classification>\n" +
" <marketSector>Curncy</marketSector>\n" +
" </classification>\n" +
" <adpDetails>\n" +
" <adpSrcFlag>false</adpSrcFlag>\n" +
" <adpPrivateRangeFlag>false</adpPrivateRangeFlag>\n" +
" </adpDetails>\n" +
" <BRDRVersionDetails>\n" +
" <BRDRVersionNumber>362</BRDRVersionNumber>\n" +
" <BRDRVersionTimestamp>2021-12-10T17:47:32.103-05:00</BRDRVersionTimestamp>\n" +
" <BRDRPublishedTimestamp>2023-10-20T03:59:39.263-04:00</BRDRPublishedTimestamp>\n" +
" </BRDRVersionDetails>\n" +
" <productTaxonomy>\n" +
" <lrmProductCode>1234</lrmProductCode>\n" +
" <lrmProductDescription>Obsolete</lrmProductDescription>\n" +
" </productTaxonomy>\n" +
" <isOTISSecurity>true</isOTISSecurity>\n" +
" <isTOMSNSecurity>false</isTOMSNSecurity>\n" +
" <isPolypathSecurity>false</isPolypathSecurity>\n" +
" <ISOCountryCode>IN</ISOCountryCode>\n" +
" </cashInformation>\n" +
"</securityDataUpdated>";

Document doc = getDocFromString(xml);
System.out.println(getValueFromXml("/*//identifier[@type='BRDR-UNIQUE-ID']/text()", doc));
}

public static Document getDocFromString(String xml) throws Exception {
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
return builder.parse(is);
}

public static String getValueFromXml(String xPathExpr, Document doc) throws XPathExpressionException {
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xPathExpr);
Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
return node != null ? node.getNodeValue() : null;
}
}
```

In lower environments, this code successfully prints the value for any valid `XPath`. However, in production, the `getValueFromXml` method returns null for the same `XPath` expressions.

Upon remote debugging in production using IntelliJ, I noticed that `getDocFromString` returns a different structure of the Document object (`XMLDocument`) in production, as opposed to `DeferredDocumentImpl` in the lower environments. In the lower environment, the Document object structure consists of `fNodeCount`, `fNodeType`, etc., whereas in production, the Document object contains fields like "`err`" and `validateErrNodeStr = "oracle.xml.schemavalidator.nodeerr"`, `validateErrParentStr = "oracle.xml.schemavalidator.parenterr"`.

**Dev (Lower environment)**

[image]

**Production**

[image]

I'm puzzled as to why the Document structure is different in production, given that the same code, XML, and JDK (Java 8) version are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` searches the classpath for a DOM implementation. Similarly `XPathFactory.newInstance()` searches the classpath for an XPath implementation. If you have different DOM and/or XPath libraries on the classpath, then you will get different results. In principle they should be compatible, and I can't immediately see why that isn't the case.

It might be because you haven't called `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`, and the behaviour of XPath on non-namespace-aware DOM isn't well defined.

I would actually expect your XPath expression to select nothing, because the `identifier` element is in a namespace, but you are searching for an `identitifer` element in no namespace.

Generally I think the JAXP "factory" mechanism needs to be used with great caution. If you want your application to be able to run with any JAXP library that happens to be present on the classpath, then you should test the application thoroughly to make sure it works with all popular libraries. If you've only tested it with one library, then you should load that one explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, @Michel Kay . After your answer, I understood the problem. The `XMLDocument` object from the production environment is from the dependency “xmlparserv2”, whereas in the lower environments, the `DeferredDocumentImpl` object is from the “xercesImpl” dependency. Both jars are present in the classpath in both environments and that’s the issue. But I am wondering why the behaviour is different despite having the same set of libraries in the classpath in both environments.?

Comment: Perhaps the search order is different. Whatever the cause, it's a good idea for the application to be specific about choosing a specific implementation, and to make sure that the implementation you test against is the same as the one you use in production.